# How to port Windows C++ that handles unicode with tchar.h to iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, winapi, unicode, tchar

I have some c++ code that I need to integrate into an iOS app. The windows c++ code handles unicode using tchar.h. I have made the following defines for iOS:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#define _T(x)     x
#define TCHAR       char
#define _tremove    unlink
#define _stprintf   sprintf
#define _sntprintf vsnprintf
#define _tcsncpy wcsncpy
#define _tcscpy wcscpy
#define _tcscmp wcscmp
#define _tcsrchr wcsrchr
#define _tfopen fopen
```

When trying to build the app many of these are either missing (ex. wcscpy) or have the wrong arguments. The coder responsible for the c++ code said I should use char instead of wchar so I defined TCHAR as char. Does anyone have a clue as to how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `TCHAR` (and FYI, it is `_TCHAR` in the C runtime, `TCHAR` is for the Win32 API) is to allow code to switch between either `char` or `wchar_t` APIs at compile time, but your defines are mixing them together. The `wcs` functions are for `wchar_t`, so you need to change those defines to the `char` counterparts, to match your other `char`-based defines:

```
#define _tcsncpy strncpy
#define _tcscpy strcpy
#define _tcscmp strcmp
#define _tcsrchr strrchr
```

Also, you are mapping `_sntprintf` to the wrong C function.  It needs to be mapped to `snprintf()` instead of `vsnprintf()`:

```
#define _sntprintf snprintf
```

`snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` are declared very differently:

```
int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );
int vsnprintf (char * s, size_t n, const char * format, va_list arg );
```

Which is likely why you are getting "wrong arguments" errors.

Comment: Great! Still missing #define _sntprintf vsnprintf and including wchar.h is presumably not necessary?

Comment: You are mapping `_sntprintf` to the wrong function. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok. Now I get "No matching function call to snprintf" in the line: _sntprintf( m_sErr, sizeof(m_sErr)/sizeof(m_sErr[0]), L"Tiedoston %s avaaminen ep\xE4onnistui.", pFileNimi );

Comment: Change `L"..."` to `_T("...")` in the 3rd parameter. You are passing a `wchar_t*` where a `char*` is expected. And make sure `pFileNimi` is `TCHAR`-based and not `wchar_t`-based so it matches the correct character type that the function `_sntprintf` maps to is expecting.

Comment: So I probably have to add an #ifdef macOS for the changed line?

Comment: No. `_sntprintf( m_sErr, sizeof(m_sErr)/sizeof(m_sErr[0]), _T("Tiedoston %s avaaminen ep\xE4onnistui."), pFileNimi );`, where `pFileNimi` is either a `TCHAR*` or `TCHAR[]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151526/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-melodius).